# .Net Core 6.0 API - Azure AD Authentication error

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to implement Azure AD Authentication using .Net Core 6.0.  My appsettings.json has the following configuration

```
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"Domain": "value1",
"ClientId": "value2",
"TenantId": "value2",
```

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var provider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
var configuration  = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

builder.Services.AddCors();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication(); //Azure
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Conroller class

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Validate")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Validate()
    {
    try
    {
        return Ok("Hello User");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return Ok();
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error while accessing the function through the browser (https://localhost:6677/swagger/index.html)

```
Failed to fetch.
Possible Reasons:

CORS

Network Failure

URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
```

The API console logs showing the below errors

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
      DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
      
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
      
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
      Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
      
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: OpenIdConnect was challenged.
      
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show us your whole Program.cs, so we can see how you you've added OpenApi? And do you see thw swagger interface in the browser or is the "failed to fetch" error all you can see?

Comment: I have added the program.cs code. I am getting the error while executing from the swagger interface

Answer (score 1):

For APIs, you should be calling the AddMicrosoftIdentityWeb**Api**() method. Check it here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/web-apis

This will protect your API with a bearer schema - you will need to authenticate your user on the client and acquire a proper token to call your API.

Check the following doc which explains everything in detail:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview

You can also check this official MS sample which has a simple Angular frontend calling a .NET Core Web API:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-tutorial/tree/main/3-Authorization-II/1-call-api